# BEFORE an easel or IN FRONT OF an easel

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have recently come across the phrase "BEFORE an easel" and been slightly confused by this word usage. At first I thought the author misused the preposition "before" (I have always considered it the preposition of time i.e. "before 700 B.C.") and that it should be definitely replaced by "in front of". However, having scrutinized some examples in the dictionaries, I found that both Kipling J.R. and Thackeray W.M., the English authors, did use "before" in such a phrase.

Can anybody clarify this issue for me?  Is it right to say "before an/the easel"? Or maybe is it a kind of fixed expression?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the word *before* in a good English-English dictionary?

Comment: He was brought before the King. He served before the mast. 'Behold the judge standeth before the door' James 5:9.

Comment: "Putting the cart before the horse". There are lots of examples. The part I'm confused about is whether it's the artist who stands before the easel or the subject of the portrait.

Comment: @Pam  It is the artist.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/before  HTH

Comment: It used to be a part of normal speech giving, as @Pam says, 'putting the cart before the horse' but is now a bit archaic, formal or literary. These days we wouldn't say 'I stood before my house waiting for my friend' although people used to say things like that all the time. However we would say 'He was brought before the court' and we might say 'I stood before the hotel gazing at the magnificent view'

Comment: Where was the phrase "before the easel"? If it's from an older author, it could be (as @BoldBen says) just the current style at the time of writing. If it was a more modern work, I'd suggest the author was trying to convey a sense of grandness for the easel. NigelJ's examples (king, judge, ship) are all quite grand things.

Comment: There are still non-temporal contexts where _before_ = _in front of_ sound more or less idiomatic and sometimes in a literary style (I put the idea before the board; A huge chasm opened up before them), but 99.9% of native speakers would normally opt for 'in front of the easel'.

Comment: Please include the sentence where the phrase was used, and if possible, its source. Saying the "artist" is too vague, is the artist alive or dead? Who is the artist? An Englishman or someone whose words were translated into English? I think users are hesitant to post answers because they want to be sure that their answers won't be downvoted for unsubstantiated claims.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/652/14666 “Before” vs. “in front of”